# Why is the speed of drawing graphics slower in C# than VB6

Tags: c#, vb6, performance, graphic

Hi
I Wonder why usual graphic speed is so much slower than VB6 in C# code ,
here is a sample code which does the same thing in VB6 and C# , it takes 1.7 Secs in VB6 on my computer and 4.2 Secs in C#
Could someone please tell me why and also if there is a better and faster way in c# .

Thanks

C# Code

```
Bitmap MyBitmap = new Bitmap(1024, 768);
Graphics g = Graphics.FromImage(MyBitmap);
DateTime STime = DateTime.Now;
Pen MyPen = new Pen(Color.Black);
for (int i = 0; i < 100000; i++)
{
    g.DrawLine (MyPen, 0, 0, 1024, 768);
}
MessageBox.Show(DateTime.Now.Subtract(STime).TotalMilliseconds.ToString());
```

VB6 Code :

```
Me.AutoRedraw = True
t = Timer
For i = 1 To 100000
    Me.Line (0, 0)-(1024, 768), 0
Next
MsgBox (Timer - t)
```

Comment: You should use stopwatch in C# for timing as opposed to DateTime - it might not be much of a difference here, but it's the advised way of measuring.

Comment: DateTime isn't really suited for timing. Use Stopwatch instead.

Comment: thanks, I Used StopWatch but it doesn't differ that much ,If needed , I will post this code , the time was 4.19

Answer (score 4, accepted):

VB6 goes straight to GDI. C#, which uses System.Drawing, uses GDI+. GDI+ is antialiased and uses 32bpp. Basically, there is a bunch of overhead.